# Как вынести общие метода С++?

Tags: c++, ооп, c++11

У меня есть классы Circle и Rectangle, они наследуются от базового класса Figure.
Как мне вынести общую логику классов, что-бы код не повторялся?
Данные примеры минимализированы:

***Figure.h***:

```
class Figure
{
    sf::Shape* figure_object_;
    sf::Color* color_;
public:
    virtual void show();
```

***Circle.h***:

```
class Circle final :
    public Figure
{
    sf::CircleShape* figure_object_;
    sf::Color* color_;
public:
    void show() override;
```

***Circle.cpp***:

```
void Circle::show()
{
    figure_object_->setFillColor(*color_);
}
```

***Rectangle.h***:

```
class Rectangle:
    public Figure
{
    sf::RectangleShape* figure_object_;
    sf::Color* color_;
public:
    void show() override;
```

***Rectangle.cpp***:

```
void Rectangle::show()
{
    figure_object_->setFillColor(*color_);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум, не надо повторять в дочерних классах

```
sf::CircleShape* figure_object_;
sf::Color* color_;
```

`color` - стопроцентно, ну, а `figure_object_` - если `CircleShape` и `RectangleShape` - наследники `Shape` с соответствующими виртуальными функциями.

Тогда

```
figure_object_->setFillColor(*color_);
```

тоже выносится в базовый класс. При этом не нужно даже перекрывать `show()` - виртуальность сработает сама.

```
class Figure
{
protected:
    sf::Shape* figure_object_;
    sf::Color* color_;
public:
    virtual void show() { figure_object_->setFillColor(*color_); }
```

`show` я оставил виртуальным на всякий пожарный случай...

Все. Главное - верно настроить в `Circle` и `Rectangle` член `figure_object_`.

*"По-моему, так." (с) Пух*

Comment: Виртуальный метод нужно обьявлять только в header файле или и в cpp можно? А если я в Circle присваиваю значение color_, а виртуально show оно будет учитыватся? Так как в Figure, я color_ просто обьявляю...

Comment: Объявлять там, где вы объявляете класс. Да, будет. Да, я там забыл было `protected` указать, чтоб потомки могли к этим членам достучаться, уже исправил..